# How to find out how many instances of your Discord bot are running?

Tags: c#, discord.net

I have a bot that depends on many different server software running at the same time (in different computers). Like, I make my server code in Discord.NET, and then install that software in my servers.

What I'm trying to do is keep track of how many servers are running. I spent 2 hours trying to figure out a way to do this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be looking for Sharding.
Sharding allows you to have multiple instances of your bot running, but prevents them from all serving the same users, making 1 command result in 1.x responses.

To apply sharding you should use the [DiscordShardedClient](https://discord.foxbot.me/stable/api/Discord.WebSocket.DiscordShardedClient.html) and the [ShardedCommandContext](https://discord.foxbot.me/stable/api/Discord.Commands.ShardedCommandContext.html), instead of the regularly implemented [DiscordSocketClient](https://discord.foxbot.me/stable/api/Discord.WebSocket.DiscordSocketClient.html) and [CommandContext](https://discord.foxbot.me/stable/api/Discord.Commands.CommandContext.html)